# How to Mask for Ascii characters for MaskedTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have one `MaskedTextBox` component where I need to allow user to enter any ascii character. What should the `MaskFormat` for this be in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by ASCII characters?

Comment: Any special characters on the keyboard.

Comment: You still have to be more specific if you want a correct answer. Is `æ` on the keyboard? Is `Á`? What keys do you want the mask to forbid?

Comment: I want user to be allowed to type any special characters available on keyboard. I do not want to restruict. There is one field for which I want to allow plain text for user to enter.

Comment: _"I want user to be allowed to type any [...] characters available on keyboard."_ - then don't use a `MaskedTextBox`, or leave the `Mask`  property empty.

Comment: I need masked text box coz depending upon parameter settings we need to allow masking, so in that case I need to have maskedtext box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set Mask feature for using predefined masks.

[image]

or you can write your mask into **Mask** textbox here (or **Mask Property** in **Properties Window**)

And [this is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.asciionly.aspx) about MaskedTextBox's **AsciiOnly** property.

Comment: One more doubt, How do I achieve for MillBrookMaskEdit box in .rc file in VC++ ?